# Twitter4j FilterQuery language() method missing

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I'm using Twitter4j to access the Twitter streaming API, and I want to limit the tweets I get from the sample stream to English language tweets. I had thought that the way to do this would be as follows, based on the [Javadoc](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/FilterQuery.html#language%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29):

```
    FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();

    String[] lang = { "en" };
    fq.language(lang);// = "test";

    twitterStream.filter(fq);
```

But, when I try and run that, I get a compiler error saying the FilterQuery objects don't have a public language method. Does anyone know what's going on?

Edit: I'm using version 3.0.3 of the JAR file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That feature has not been implemented yet. There's an open ticket [TFJ-764](http://jira.twitter4j.org/browse/TFJ-764) as part of the 3.0.4 for supporting tweet's metadata.